# PDO : using bound parameters inside a function

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to MySQL, and I have an issue as follows :
Given that code

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':param0', $params[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':param1', $params[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':param2', $params[2]);
```

Then, I want to call a function foo($stmt,...), How can I use the array $params inside that function which would assign new values for each element of the $params array?

Comment: You wouldn't.  You would call the function before building the statement.  `bindParam` is going to get the VALUE of `$params[0]`.  If you change `$params[0]`, that doesn't update the bind.

Comment: @TimRoberts `bindParam()` binds to references, not values. `bindValue()` would get the values of the parameters.

Comment: I don't know why my question got -1 !

Comment: but such a function makes no sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the `$params` array to the function by reference, since the parameters are bound to references to the caller's array.

```
function foo($stmt, &$params) {
    $params[0] = 1;
    $params[1] = "abc";
    $params[2] = "xxx";
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':param0', $params[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':param1', $params[1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':param2', $params[2]);
foo($stmt, $params);
```

Comment: It works ! thank you very much